# C++, checking two txt files via fstream library to concatenate lines with the same ID

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I have to make a program which checks two txt files and concatenates the lines which start with the same ID. The results must be in a new file The files are in the following format:

ID STRING_UP_TO_30_CHARS

Error checking is not necessary but I have been stressing over this for quite a while now. I'm pretty new to programming in general as I am a freshman in University.

Code that I have right now:

```
int main()
{
  temp();

  fstream file1;
  fstream file2;
  ofstream result;

  string line1, line2;
  int pos1, pos2;
  string id1, id2;


  file1.open("first.txt");
  file2.open("second.txt");
  result.open("resultat.txt");

  while(getline(file1, line1))
  {
    pos1 = line1.find(" "); //id and word are seperated by a space character, so I find the position of this space character

    id1 = line1;
    id1.erase(id1.begin()+pos1, id1.end()); //id is now a digit but string,


    while(getline(file2,line2))
    {
      pos2 = line2.find(" ");

      id2 = line2;
      id2.erase(id2.begin()+pos2, id2.end()); //id is digit now
      if(id2 == id1)
        {
          result<<line1<<" "<<line2<<endl;
          // line2.erase(line2.begin(), line2.end());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I made a function to make a temp file of the 2nd file since I tried deleting lines from the second document to make the code work. Simply ignore the temp() for now.

The problem is that it only creates 2 lines in my result.txt file. I also have to add all the lines which are not paired with any lines from the other txt file as seperate lines in the final file but this is not a problem for me at the moment.

Txt files I'm testing are probably important:

```
21 para
23 dyta
27 treta
11 katert
12 pest
13 fundit
14 jojo
41 vecant
46 vecanti
```

```
12 fifth
21 first
23 second
29 third
11 fourth
13 last
14 nono
91 special
104 specialty
```

The result i get is:

```
21 para 21 first
23 dyta 23 second
```

I have seen people suggesting vectors but I have not learned them at school and I am also not permitted to use any other libraries for my application.

Comment: A `map` or `unordered_map` sounds like a perfect fit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know this is a learning forum but I need a way to edit my current code and not use map(I'll have to pretty much learn it from scratch since I screwed up and skipped the 2 classes that map was explained on). I'm already multitasking too much and jumping from one language(one of them an actual foreign language that the law requires me to learn)  to another and losing my sanity in the process. Thanks for the input nonetheless.

Comment: Well, if `std::map`'s ***were*** presented as class material, beforehand, then it is pretty clear that you are expected to use them here, for this assignment, and even if you manage to get it working without using them, you will not receive a passing grade for this homework assignment.

Comment: I have a bunch of exercises I am supposed to turn in before the semester ends and the way I complete them does not matter. I understand where you're coming from and you are completely right, there is an order on how you learn things and it is important to not slack like I did, I feel like I've been playing catch-up ever since. Once again thank you for the solution you gave.

Comment: You _could_ use a vector as a map replacement. Read the whole file into a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` and sort it. Then when you read the second file, use `std::lower_bound` to check if the `id` of each record is present in the first vector - but as @SamVarshavchik said, if they have had lessons explaining `map`s, just go for that. It's actually simpler than using the vector workaround. Just look at som map examples here on SO and you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(getline(file2,line2))
```

After this inner loop finds the line from the 2nd file that matches the 1st line in the first file, the outer loop runs again to read the 2nd line from the first file.

However, afterwards, this inner loop simply ***continues reading from the 2nd file*** from the point ***where it stopped reading*** on the previous iteration of the outer loop. It found the first line, and the `while` loop terminated. Now, it again continues to `getline` from `file2`, so it simply continues reading the rest of it.

The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming states: "a computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". Its corollary states: "a computer never does what you never tell it to do".

In this case you did not tell your computer to start at the beginning of the 2nd file, to begin searching it again for the line that matches the 2nd line from the first file. So, your computer never did that.

Your C++ textbook should explain how to use `seekg` to seek the position where your `fstream` reads the file contents from. You simply need to explicitly `seekg` back to the beginning of `file2` before the inner `while` loop, so that it always start reading from the very beginning of the 2nd file.

Comment: What you're saying is when I use break and the inner loop is called again, it does not start from the beginning of the 2nd file? If yes, if I use seekg (which I've never used so far) to make the inner loop read from the beginning of the 2nd file, the program should work correctly?

Also we don't even have textbooks these days. Long gone are those days I guess.

Comment: Your understanding of my answer is correct. Either use `seekg`, or declare `file2` ***and open it*** in the outer loop, which has the effect of opening the file, each time, in the outer loop. And there are plenty of C++ textbooks around. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, and it cannot be learn effectively from random Youtube videos or hacking web sites, but only from a quality textbook.

Comment: Sam you are a lifesaver. Everything works just fine now, I simply have to do the final touches.